# How to set the value of a field in a django model equal to the return of a function

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to make the "available" field equal to the return of a function that uses the "ethAddress" field as a paramater to return the amount of ether in that addresses account.

### **function to get amount of eth in an address**

```
def getAddressAmount(address):

   balance = web3.eth.getBalance(address)

   return web3.fromWei(balance, "ether")
```

---

**My models.py file**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from web3apps.getData import getAddressAmount

class Advertisement(models.Model):

    ethAddress = models.CharField(max_length=42, default='')


    available = getAddressAmount(ethAddress)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("advertisement-update", kwargs={"id": self.id})


    def __str__(self):
        return self.ad
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**According to your logic, I don't think you should save "`available`" in model. You can easily access value using `property of model`.**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from web3apps.getData import getAddressAmount

class Advertisement(models.Model):

    ethAddress = models.CharField(max_length=42, default='') 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("advertisement-update", kwargs={"id": self.id})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ad

    @property
    def available(self)
        balance = web3.eth.getBalance(self.ethAddress)
        return web3.fromWei(balance, "ether")
```

This is easy for you to calculate at run time when you need and it will some same as your model field value.

Like:

```
a = Advertisement.objects.get(id=1)
a.available
```

**# this will call you property that define in model can access same way as field in model.**